# How to check if video player is buffering using adobe flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, actionscript-3

Hi i have currently creating a video player using adobe flex and i want to check if the video is buffering could anyone help me to solve this. I am a beginner in flex and i thought it was built in. Please help

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: Yes i am trying to find out on how to create a simple customize loader when the video is buffering or not. Is there any simple function? I don't know where to start